# Is possible to simplify multiple UNION ALL in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have a MySQL query that always needs to compare 4 values, I need to add that values with rows using UNION ALL, but this code looks very large and I want to simplify it. 
The code is the following:

```
SELECT
    trimestre,

IF ((meta = 0) OR (meta is null) or not(meta REGEXP '[0-9]+'), :meta, meta) as valor
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            trimestre,
            valor AS meta
        FROM
            view_valores_indicadores
        WHERE
            anio = :anio
        AND codigo_indicador = :codigo_indicador
        AND alias_campo = 'meta'
        UNION ALL
            SELECT
                1,
                :meta
            UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    2,
                    :meta
                UNION ALL
                    SELECT
                        3,
                        :meta
                    UNION ALL
                        SELECT
                            4,
                            :meta
                        ORDER BY
                            trimestre ASC
    ) AS T
GROUP BY
    TRIMESTRE
```

I want to know if is possible to simplify that multiple UNION ALL's like

```
UNION ALL SELECT (row1, row1, row3...)
```

Comment: use a re-usable helper table with known contiguous id's

Comment: Like @Drew said, you can use a helper table where all those helper ids reside. Then you need to use one `UNION ALL` like this `...UNION ALL SELECT id, :meta From your_helper_table....`

Comment: Don't rush to 'simplify' code. If it works, and works efficiently, then you should have no problem with it.

Comment: Well having a block of a hundred or thousands of unions in one statement  would be pretty embarrassing and those answers come from this site. Unions don't scale. Avoid them like the plague. Usually a sign of a horrible design

Comment: @Drew is not horrible, I believe fot this special case is useful

Comment: Do what most people might do, hide them all on one line without line breaks so you can forget they are there :p

Comment: @Drew :p :p :p :p